# HEXAGON DSP Porting

Tags: hexagon-dsp

I want to port our algorithm using HVX intrinsics of Hexagon DSP but am unable to understand how to use them  and one more question is i have used vector 64 bit intrinsics but when i profile the code cycles are less for C code than using vector intrinsics and also am using Hexaon timer api's to calculate cycles.
This is the code:
C code:
cycles consumed is 5452

```
for(i=0;i<=128;i++){
value[i]=((hs_int32)((((hs_int32)(hs_int16)((32767)))*((hs_int32) 
  (hs_int16)((((window[i])) >> (15))))))+(hs_int32)((((((hs_int32) 
   (hs_int16)((32767)))*((hs_int32)(hs_int16) 
    (((window[i])&0x00007fff))))) >> (15))));
  }
```

Hexagon intrinsics:
Cycles consumed are 8766

```
for(i=0,j=0;i<=128/2;i++,j++) 
{   
   Word64 and_op=Q6_P_and_PP(R_E_VECTOR_1[i],dummy);
   shift_1[i+j]=Q6_R_asr_RI(shift_1[i+j],15);
   shift_1[i+1+j]=Q6_R_asr_RI(shift_1[i+1+j],15);
   Word64 first_op=Q6_P_vmpyweh_PP_sat(leak2_64,R_E_VECTOR_1[i]);
   out[i]=Q6_P_vmpyweh_PP_sat(leak2_64,and_op);
   shift_2[i+j]=Q6_R_asr_RI(shift_2[i+j],15);
   shift_2[i+1+j]=Q6_R_asr_RI(shift_2[i+1+j],15);
   out[i]=Q6_P_vaddw_PP(first_op,out[i]);
}
```

C code is showing less cycles compared to using hexagon intrinsics.Anyone can help me regarding this problem.

@Brain cain,
This is the dissassembly of intrinsics version:

```
                      r1:0 = memd(r30+#-48)

 000000000000c400:    r2 = memw(r30+#-52)
 000000000000c404:    r3 = memw(r30+#-20)
 000000000000c408:    r5:4 = memd(r2+r3<<#3)
 000000000000c40c:    r1:0 = vmpyweh(r1:0,r5:4):sat
 000000000000c410:    memd(r30+#-192) = r1:0
 194                   out[i]=Q6_P_vmpyweh_PP_sat(leak2_64,and_op);
 000000000000c414:    r1:0 = memd(r30+#-48)
 000000000000c418:    r5:4 = memd(r30+#-184)
 000000000000c41c:    r1:0 = vmpyweh(r1:0,r5:4):sat
 000000000000c420:    r2 = memw(r30+#-84)
 000000000000c424:    r3 = memw(r30+#-20)
 000000000000c428:    memd(r2+r3<<#3) = r1:0 
195                   shift_2[i+j]=Q6_R_asr_RI(shift_2[i+j],15);
  000000000000c42c:    r2 = memw(r30+#-148)
  000000000000c430:    r3 = memw(r30+#-20)
  000000000000c434:    r6 = memw(r30+#-24)
  000000000000c438:    r3 = add(r3,r6)
000000000000c43c:    r6 = memw(r2+r3<<#2)
000000000000c440:    r6 = asr(r6,#15)
000000000000c444:    memw(r2+r3<<#2) = r6
 196                   shift_2[i+1+j]=Q6_R_asr_RI(shift_2[i+1+j],15);
 000000000000c448:    r2 = memw(r30+#-148)
 000000000000c44c:    r3 = memw(r30+#-20)
 000000000000c450:    r6 = memw(r30+#-24)
 000000000000c454:    r3 = add(r3,r6)
              mt_cv_mec_power_spectrum_fixed_hexagon:
 000000000000c458:    r2 = addasl(r2,r3,#2)
 000000000000c45c:    r3 = memw(r2+#4)
 000000000000c460:    r3 = asr(r3,#15)
 000000000000c464:    memw(r2+#4) = r3
 197                out[i]=Q6_P_vaddw_PP(first_op,out[i]);
 000000000000c468:    r1:0 = memd(r30+#-192)
 000000000000c46c:    r2 = memw(r30+#-84)
 000000000000c470:    r3 = memw(r30+#-20)
 000000000000c474:    r5:4 = memd(r2+r3<<#3)
 000000000000c478:    r1:0 = vaddw(r1:0,r5:4)
 000000000000c47c:    memd(r2+r3<<#3) = r1:0
                }
```

Iam new to DSP programming and facing alot of issues to understand the hexagon DSP .Your help will be very helpful for me .

Comment: Can you include the unabridged C code example?  How did you build it?  (`-O3`, e.g.?)
And can you share the disassembly of the intrinsics version?  Are these instructions getting bundled into packets effectively?

Comment: Thank you Brain cain for replying.I actually built it in hexagon simulator using command  "make V=hexagon_Debug_dynamic_toolv83_v65". and I have used hexagon timer API's to calculate cycle consumption.Actually our algorithm takes 500 t0 600 MCPS in different platforms but in hexagon it is showing very less cycles.I  actually want to know about packets ,what it does and relation between the cycles consumption and packets.

Comment: Please include the unabridged C code and intrinsics code and I will take a closer look.

Comment: What do you mean by unabridged C code?

Comment: unabridged: meaning complete.  Here on SO they sometimes call it an MCVE or RepRex - https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex